# Unable to dynamically set a Input of type check box as required using javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sharepoint

I am working on a sharepoint 2013 edit aspx form. now I have the following checkbox:

```
<span title="Yes" class="ms-RadioText">
<input id="UpdateOrder_0e0052d6-9924-4774-b50d-d7ef364d744a_MultiChoiceOption_0" required="" type="checkbox">
<label for="UpdateOrder_0e0052d6-9924-4774-b50d-d7ef364d744a_MultiChoiceOption_0">Yes</label>
</span>
```

[image]

now I want under certain conditions to set this checkbox as required, so users can not submit the form unless they check this checkbox. so I wrote the following javascript:

```
var orderstatus0 = $('select[id^="OrderStatus_"]').val();
if (orderstatus0 == "Invoiced")
    {

        $('input[id^="UpdateOrder_"]').required;
        var x = document.getElementById('UpdateOrder_0e0052d6-9924-4774-b50d-d7ef364d744a_MultiChoiceOption_0').required;
        document.getElementById('UpdateOrder_0e0052d6-9924-4774-b50d-d7ef364d744a_MultiChoiceOption_0').required= true;
        alert(x);                               
    }
```

but currently no validation will be applied, even inside the alert i was excepting to get `true`, but I am getting `false`.. so can anyone advice on this please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the code below into a script editor web part in the editform page.

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function PreSaveAction(){
    var orderstatus0 = $('select[id^="OrderStatus_"]').val();
    $("#updateordermsg").remove();
    if (orderstatus0 == "Invoiced"){    
        if($('input[id^="UpdateOrder_"]').is(':checked')){
            return true;
        }else{          
            $('input[id^="UpdateOrder_"]').closest("td").append("<span id='updateordermsg' style='color:red'><br/>Please check the UpdateOrder.</span>");          
            return false;
        }
    }else{
        return true;
    }
}
</script>
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. the validation worked well. but having a popup windows does not look compatible with how sharepoint handle required fields.. so can i show a message beside the checkbox that this checkbox must be checked?

Answer (score 1):

You should use `.att()` [jQuery function](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) to set the attribute to the element.

```js
var orderstatus0 = $('select[id^="OrderStatus_"]').val();
$('input[id^="UpdateOrder_"]').attr("required", "required");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <span title="Yes" class="ms-RadioText">
    <input id="UpdateOrder_0e0052d6-9924-4774-b50d-d7ef364d744a_MultiChoiceOption_0" type="checkbox">
    <label for="UpdateOrder_0e0052d6-9924-4774-b50d-d7ef364d744a_MultiChoiceOption_0">Yes</label>
  </span>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: unfortunelty this did not work either, still i can un-check this check box and submit my form...

Comment: I do not think you can because the required attribute has been set to the checkbox. May be that is the browser problem.